# Ненормативная лексика у Пушкина

Tags: стилистика

Почему в школьных учебниках литературы выражение: "Ай да Пушкин, ай да сукин сын!" пишут прямым текстом? Это же ненормативная лексика и растление несовершеннолетних!!!

Comment: Еще со школы помню, как нам объясняли, что "сука" в значении "самка собаки" - вполне литературное слово, пусть и простонародное, пусть и не вполне лестное. "Ай да сукин сын!" - яркое выражение = "ай да молодец!".

Comment: А почему это слово тогда запикивают в интервью?

Comment: Спросите у тех, кто запикивает. Вообще, говорил уже неоднократно, установливать нормативность тех или иных слов в законодательном порядке - дурь величайшая. Но и наши законодатели, до любой дури падкие, тут все-таки удержались от полной самодискредитации, ограничив число подлежащих запикивани. слов четырьмя общеизвестными морфами (с производными). Так что, если запикивают, то это или редакционная политика, или личное мнение редактора, возжедавшего быть святее Папы.

Comment: +1 Бегемотусу. К тому же есть разница между "Я, сука, вчера немного на грудь принял, ну да, имею, сука, право - выходной, сука" и "ай да Пушкин - ай да сукин сын!" Даже если бы не было сегодняшнего перегиба с цензурой, я бы не особенно обиделся на запикивание "суки" в первом примере. Это может быть на усмотрении редакторов конкретного СМИ.

Answer (score 2):

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/236134

Сука, кобель - относящееся к животным, в частности - к собакам. По отношению к человеку - бранное слово, но не матерное. По сути "сукин сын" - щенок. Например, выражение "Ты еще щенок!" означает молодого, не знающего жизни. По сути - уничижительное высказывание, но очень яркое выражение как в литературе, так и в жизни... Существует и такое высказывание: "Ты, сукин сын, еще жизни не нюхал!"